# Recurring payment, receiving transaction_id

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

What is the data paypal returns if we make recurring payments through a Subscription button on the website?

How can we get transaction_id?

It's that we want our users to pay with credit cards with no need to register, but so far we can't get transaction_id to get the information for automatic processes on the website directly. Instead we have to manage it all through paypal account. How can we avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the PayPal IPN feature where you will specify your IPN url and PayPal will post to that url all the transaction related data which includes transaction id as well. Below is the sample data that generally posted when subscription transaction gets completed.

```
Array
(
    [0] => mc_gross=12.00
    [1] => protection_eligibility=Eligible
    [2] => address_status=confirmed
    [3] => payer_id=XCACACACCAX
    [4] => address_street=1+Main+St%0D%0Aasdasf
    [5] => payment_date=02%3A52%3A45+Jul+21%2C+2014+PDT
    [6] => payment_status=Completed
    [7] => charset=UTF-8
    [8] => address_zip=95131
    [9] => first_name=Test+Personal+Test
    [10] => mc_fee=0.65
    [11] => address_country_code=US
    [12] => address_name=AAAA+Personal+Test+Account
    [13] => notify_version=3.8
    [14] => subscr_id=I-SAD8U8BK8E62
    [15] => payer_status=verified
    [16] => business=TEST%40business.co.in
    [17] => address_country=United+States
    [18] => address_city=San+Jose
    [19] => verify_sign=AitFUzqO8ZXxGicaEa14GLIKyp.1AiUxEhkGTuMGalNusuo72mQApzS1
    [20] => payer_email=TESTING%40personal.co.in
    [21] => contact_phone=408-767-7151
    **[22] => txn_id=3XN896582B789115H**
    [23] => payment_type=instant
    [24] => last_name=Account
    [25] => address_state=CA
    [26] => receiver_email=TEST%40business.co.in
    [27] => payment_fee=0.65
    [28] => receiver_id=XXXXXXXX
    [29] => txn_type=subscr_payment
    [30] => item_name=csacdas
    [31] => mc_currency=USD
    [32] => residence_country=US
    [33] => test_ipn=1
    [34] => transaction_subject=csacdas
    [35] => payment_gross=12.00
    [36] => ipn_track_id=cbe04d91c0d90
)
```

You can get more info related to IPN [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) .

And if you are willing to provide the buyers to pay via credit card (with having PayPal account) then you need to sign up for the ERP(Enhanced Recurring Payments ) which is an add on. You can use [this](https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/erp_overview) for more info .